# Sort an array using Castle.DynamicProxy in C#

Tags: c#, aop, aspect, castle-dynamicproxy

I am trying to learn AOP. I have a method returning array.

```
public class ReturnCollection
{
    public virtual Array ReturnArrayStringData()
    {
        string[] IntArray = { "1", "a", "4", "'", "&", "g" };
        foreach (var item in IntArray)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        }
        return IntArray;
    }
}
```

I want to sort this array using Castle.DynamicProxy and ArrayName.sort(). Here is my proxy Method.

```
[Serializable]
public abstract class Interceptor: IInterceptor
{
    protected abstract void ExecuteAfter(IInvocation invocation);
    public void Intercept(IInvocation invocation)
    {
        invocation.Proceed();
        ExecuteAfter(invocation);
    }
}

    public class ExecuteAfterMethod: Interceptor
{
    protected override void ExecuteAfter(Castle.DynamicProxy.IInvocation invocation)
    {
        //sort array here.
    }
}
```

How can I do it? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you just needed to implement the method, one option would be to reassign `invocation.ReturnValue`:

```
public class ExecuteAfterMethod : Interceptor
{
    protected override void ExecuteAfter(Castle.DynamicProxy.IInvocation invocation)
    {
        var stringArray = (invocation.ReturnValue as string[]).Reverse().ToArray(); // here will have the object typed as String[], so printing it should be no problem.
    foreach(var item in stringArray) {
         Console.WriteLine(item);
    }
    invocation.ReturnValue = stringArray; // and finally we reassign the result
    }
}
```

Comment: I got error.   'Unhandled exception. System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'source')
   at System.Linq.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentNullException(ExceptionArgument argument)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.Reverse[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at YonOdaklıProje.Interceptor.Intercept(IInvocation invocation) in line 16
   at Castle.DynamicProxy.AbstractInvocation.Proceed()
   at Castle.Proxies.KoleksiyonDöndürProxy.ReturnListStringData()
   at YonOdaklıProje.Program.Main(String[] args) in line 13'

Comment: You mind setting a breakpoint, inspecting `invocation` in debugger and checking what `ReturnValue` is? I suspect it's either null or not array of string for whatever reason. So whatever type it is - you'd have to adjust the type cast.

Comment: Oh I solved it thanks. I want to print it to screen with console writline. System.String[] says on the screen. How can i see array's elements?

Comment: The same way you do it in `ArrayStringData` is an option: after your reverse line, do something like `foreach (var item in invocation.ReturnValue) { Console.WriteLine(item); }`

Comment: I tried it and "foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'object' because 'object' does not contain a public instance definition for 'GetEnumerator'"

Comment: Oh, true is an object now. I'll update the answer in a sec